# left join tsql using brackets after join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have seen some TSQL code in a sproc, I am not sure what it does I have BOL and Google no joy.

```
select @A = count(1)
from tablea a 
left join fnb (Null, Null, Null ,Null ,1 , 2) b on a.userid
```

I am confused what this bit is doing:

`(Null, Null, Null ,Null ,1 , 2)`

Any reference so I can learn more would be appreciated.

Comment: `tableb` is most probably a set returning *function* not a table.

Comment: That is possible I will check

Comment: cheers horse ,That is correct I will start my research again

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Should the query then not CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY? Don't think you can join with a TV-function this way?

Comment: @TT. I think the `apply` is only necessary when you want to access columns from the joined table. If you only pass constants it is not necessary I think.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah yes, getting confused here :). You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tableb is a set returning function not a table